# How to define a non-database relationship for the Views module

Tags: views

Basically, I have an array of nids (node ids) stored in a `$_SESSION` variable, which is updated according to user actions (it holds a history of visited node pages). 
Now, I would like to create a view which displays a list of nodes, filtered by nids given in a `$_SESSION` variable.

For example:
if `$_SESSION['my_nids'] == [1,5,6]`
=> I want to display nodes 1,5,6 in the view.

Storing the nids in a db table is not an option due to performance reasons.

Can someone point me how to create such a non-database relationship views handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [views php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. And you can get the `$_SESSION['my_nids']` with in view. Actually you can do anything there that can be done with PHP.

Please note that this will again have a performance hit if the code is large. for simple things you go this route.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a normal views field handler but give it a key/machine name that isn't a database table. This is explained in the Views advanced help.